# all erc 721 tokens being collectibles

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, tokens, erc-721

Considering all NFTs are unique, are all erc 721 tokens collectibles? I'm asking this because on the Etherscan website some NFTs have the collectibles tag and some do not.

Comment: Please describe your use of the word "collectable" so your question can be answerable.

Comment: I think "collectable" would mean something that holds a unique value because of the kind of entity that it represents and not because of an ownership or service it provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. ERC721 tokens can represent anything you want. It can be a collectible 'digital item', but it can also represent things like ownership of a smart contract or a specific basket of currencies (e.g. 1.34 ETH + 157 DAI)